# SVG animation not working as expected

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I am working on SVG animation where I want to draw a rectangle using svg `stroke` animation. 
Here is my code.

```css
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1400;
  stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  animation: dash 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="100 300 500 600" enable-background="new 0 0 340 333" xml:space="preserve"><path id="XMLID_348_" class="st0 laptop-outer path" d="M523.9,704.5H119.3c-9.1,0-16.5-7.1-16.5-15.8V449.5c0-14.1,12-25.6,26.8-25.6h384.2     c14.8,0,26.8,11.5,26.8,25.6v239.1C540.5,697.4,533.1,704.5,523.9,704.5z M129.5,425.5c-13.9,0-25.2,10.8-25.2,24.1v239.1 c0,7.9,6.7,14.3,15,14.3h404.6c8.2,0,15-6.4,15-14.3V449.5c0-13.3-11.3-24.1-25.2-24.1H129.5z" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" /></svg>
```

I want to draw a rectangle from one point to the last point but it's not working as I expected.

Comment: The path isn't a simple rounded rect shape, it's a complex thing that runs back on itself. You need to redraw the path.

Comment: my graphics designer give me this from AI,
Is there any specific technique to export simple path from AI?

Comment: It needs to be a single (thick) path that goes around the rectangle once only. Your shape is actually two rectangles, one inside the other, with a fill in between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider an easier path for your SVG:

```css
path {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-dasharray: 212;
  stroke-dashoffset: 212;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 64 64' width='200'>
  <path stroke-width=0.5 d='M0 16 L0 32 C0 48 0 48 16 48 L48 48 C64 48 64 48 64 32 L64 16 C64 0 64 0 48 0 L16 0 C0 0 0 0 0 16 Z' />
</svg>
```